# Dúvida para transpor parte de uma tabela com Python

Tags: python

Estou precisando de ajuda para construir um script em Python que transponha parte de um csv como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[[0A,0B,0C,0D,0E,0F]
[01,02,03,04,05,06]
[07,08,09,10,11,12]
[13,14,15,16,17,18]
[19,20,21,22,23,24]]
```

nisso:

```
[[0A,0B,0C]
[01,02,03]
[01,02,04]
[01,02,05]
[01,02,06]
[07,08,09]
[07,08,10]
[07,08,11]
.
.
.
[19,20,24]]
```

Alguém já fez esse tipo de transposição de um csv/xls via python ?

Comment: Nunca esqueça de postar o que voçê tentou fazer para resolver o problema, até mesmo para dar uma base para quem for responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `map` e [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

data = [[10,11,12,13,14,15],
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[7,8,9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16,17,18],
[19,20,21,22,23,24]]

result = chain(*map(lambda line: [line[:2] + [line[i]] for i in range(2, 6)], data))
print(list(result))

[[10, 11, 12], [10, 11, 13], [10, 11, 14], [10, 11, 15], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 10], [7, 8, 11], [7, 8, 12], [13, 14, 15], [13, 14, 16], [13, 14, 17], [13, 14, 18], [19, 20, 21], [19, 20, 22], [19, 20, 23], [19, 20, 24]]
```

No lugar de `chain`, você pode usar `sum` se não quiser importar nada:

```
result = sum(map(lambda line: [line[:2] + [line[i]] for i in range(2, 6)], data), [])
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ! deu certo aqui !

Comment: Aproveitando para compartilhar o outro código que funcionou: 
result = [M[0][:3]] + list(chain(*[[x[:2] + [y] for y in x[2:]] for x in M[1:]]))